# This C program runs as expected on other computers but behaves strangely on my computer

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

Well this is really strange!

Here is a C program to find the subsets of a given set of integers with a constant sum

- Here is the program : [**sum_of_subsets.c**](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16825824/)

I am running Ubuntu-GNOME with **gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413.**,

When I run this program on my computer, (with exactly same input) I get strange garbage output

- [**Strange_output_on_my_laptop.txt**](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16825912/)

But when I run the same program on other systems, I get **expected** output

- [**Output_on_other_systems.txt**](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16825982/)

**What I tried:**

- **1)** I thought there is some problem with my **`gcc`** so I reinstalled with

  **`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc g++`**
- **2)** I booted into live Ubuntu from my bootable Ubuntu pendrive, (this is as weird as it gets!) and compiled and executed the same program. **It still behaves weirdly**
- **3)** Installed latest version of **`gcc`** (**`gcc-6`**), and compiled and executed the same program, it still **behaves strangly!!!**

  - [**Output_from_gcc-6.1**](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16826291/)

All other programs works perfectly on my computer.

Notice that My computer gives different outputs for the same input at different times. (example1 : set={1,2,3,4,5} , sum=5)

Comment: It almost certainly means the program has bugs resulting in Undefined Behaviour. One of the properties of UB is that it can appear to work sometimes. You'll have to use standard debugging techniques to investigate further.

Comment: Run [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on your program and you'll soon catch the issue. Reading uninitialised values leading to [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Answer (score 4):

Your code accesses `x[n]` often, without ever writing to it.

C doesn't provide any guarantees on the initial value of a variable with automatic storage duration.

You need to either assign a value to `x[n]` or avoid reading that element.

Comment: I even tried initializing the arrays to zero as `int s[20]={0},d,sum=0,n,x[20]={0},top=0,i,tot=0;` in the beginning, but still I get the garbage output

Comment: And one more thing, I get good output for Set={1,2,3,4,5} and sum=4